# Java Spring Freemarker internationalization for templates

Tags: java, spring, internationalization, freemarker

I am trying to do internationalization for my templates but i'm not sure if it's most efficient way to do it like this.

I extracted messages to resource bundle and i use MessageSource method `getMessage(String var1, @Nullable Object[] var2, Locale var3)` to get translation based on Locale, then i put it into model and process the template.

```
private String processTemplate(String templateName, String locale) {
    try {
      String greeting = messageSource.getMessage("messages.greeting", null, new Locale(locale));
      Map<String, String> model = new HashMap<>();
      model.put("greeting", greeting);
      Template template = freemarkerConfiguration.getConfiguration().getTemplate(templateName);
      return FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(template, model);
    } catch (IOException | TemplateException e) {
      log.error("Error when processing template {}", templateName);
      throw new EmailNotSentException();
    }
  }
```

My question is if there is more efficient way to process template in this manner ? Or it would be better to have internatiolization for templates ?

Comment: If the answer suited your problem, you can accept it for other readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If you use those templates as your main ui renderers, internationalize the message is the better option. But if those templates are for "emailing" I'll opt for their internationalization. 
In my application I have a similar use case, and I defined my templates like:

`order-template-fr.ftl`, `order-template-es.ftl`, `order-template-en.ftl`, ...

I resolve the template at runtime basing on the user's locale, using `LOCALE_CONTRY.toLowerCase()`. Example:

```
String template = "order-template-"+LOCALE_CONTRY.toLowerCase()+".ftl";
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to keep only one template file and instead have a property file for each language - for example lang.properties, lang_de.properties, etc? It seems to me like it would be a cleaner solution.

Comment: You can easily do it as you manage messages for different locales. I guess you already have `messages_<locale>.properties` files, so you can put your messages there then get them and setting them to your template before rendering it. That means you have to manage variables in messages.properties. Even if possible, I prefer the first solution where you can use the powerfull templating features provided by Freemarker.